# Azure node.js script: TypeError: Object #<Query> has no method 'toQueryObject'

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, mobile

I'm trying to write a TodoItem.read.js method to convert the sample TodoItem program for Azure Mobile for iOS to use Table Storage.  I am now successfully inserting items, but I can't read them yet.

Here's the error that node.js is throwing:
    Error in script '/table/TodoItem.read.js'. TypeError: Object # has no method
     'toQueryObject'
    [external code]
    at read (:12:14)
    at :1:6
    [external code]

And here's my code:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService();
var query = new azure.TableQuery()
  .select()
  .where('PartitionKey eq ?', 'learningazure');


function read(query, user, request) {

    console.log('query: ', query);

    tableSvc.queryEntities('TodoItem',query, null, function(error, result, response) {
        if(!error) {
            // query was successful
            request.respond(200, result);
            console.log('result: ', result);
            console.log('response: ', response);
        } else {
            console.log('Error calling read()');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my problem was that I was creating the

```
var query = new azure.TableQuery()
```

object outside of the `read()` function.  Simple answer is, the `query` object I created wasn't in scope.